# What’s the closest experience to Yosemite if you cannot get a reservation?

Tags: yosemite

Yosemite still requires reservations even to drive through it, through September 30, due to Covid.

Is there a way to see some of Yosemite without going inside it?

Comment: One option might be to take the YARTS bus in: ["If you enter the park on a Yosemite Area Regional Transporation System (YARTS) bus or with an authorized tour group, you do not need an additional reservation or permit."](https://www.nps.gov/yose/planyourvisit/reservations.htm)

Comment: If you’re good with scripting languages you can run a web crawler script to auto book a reservation for you at 8am. The Yosemite site says reservations are released at 8am for a week in advance.

Comment: Yosemite does NOT require a reservation if you are simply driving through from west-to-east or east-to-west.  However without a pre-booked day pass/accommodation you are not allowed stop in the park, and if you are caught there are significant fines (it's easy to tell as all vehicles in the park are given stickers for their windscreen, with varying color)

Comment: @JonathanReez Do you want cut-rate CAPTCHAs that are hard to use? *Because that's how you get cut-rate CAPTCHAs that are hard to use*.

Comment: @Harper Recreation.gov doesn’t use Captchas as far as I can tell

Comment: I was a able to get a pass without any scripting. But now I have a different problem. I’ll leave this question here in case it helps others. BTW @doc I believe your info is incorrect during COVID rules.

Comment: for @Doc: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157800/covid-19-does-driving-from-lee-vining-to-fresno-require-a-yosemite-reservation

Comment: If [this article](https://www.fresnobee.com/news/california/yosemite/article250555564.html)'s information is still current (see #5), it appears that @Doc is correct that no reservation is required now to drive the direct route straight through the park, but it's a time-limited pass with no stopping permitted.

Comment: Or for official information, [see the park FAQ](https://www.nps.gov/yose/planyourvisit/covid19.htm) under "Do I need a day-use reservation if I am just driving through the park?" But they're very clear they mean it about driving directly from entrance to entrance without stopping, and you have to pay the fee.

Comment: @AlexR The 2021 rules are different to the 2020 rules.  No pass is needed if simply driving straight through the pass (over Tioga Pass) without stopping.

Comment: Driving straight-through is an acceptable answer, please feel free to post it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer from the comments, *at the entrance station, without a reservation, you can get a time-limited pass to drive through the park without long stops*, was the correct answer in Summer 2021.